# not to safely remove non-spinning drives will damage the hardware?

Tags: ssd, usb-flash-drive, safely-remove-hardware

I know that if we disconnect a spinning drive without safe remove, the computer may be writing some data on it and it's spinning, so it may get damaged. But is it necessary to safely remove a flash disk or an SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spinning and head parking are not as big a problem as the data that is not fully written out. Be it a hard disk or a flash disk or a SSD drive, the systems that we use them with can have data being activly written to them even when not user initiated.

Internally in the disk items whatever data that was about to be written, is not nessisarily completly in the place it will land.
Because of caches and ram usage all throughout any of these storage items, and caches via the operating systems , and file system hidden file writes and completion of journaling etc, removal of the power at any time without a complete flush of all that, would result in possible data losses.

Additionally any internal data shifing that is going on, to relocate sectors for the purpose of bad sectors , wear leveling and trim (both internally occuring , and externally initiated) Pulling the power could result in any of these operations not completing or worse being left in a state that it does not finish properly at all.

While many tricks and efforts are being applied to insure that the data is not removed until transfered, and the ease of which many file systems and disk systems would solution such problems, I do not ever intend to take the risk, nor lose any data.

There are things you can do to reduce all the things going on behind the users back, and to stop caching , and then be sure all the writes are completed prior to removal of the disk (or more importantly the power) But you must ask yourself do you feel luckey ?  well do you :-)

Comment: so sometimes data are moved from a sector to another "automatically" to do something like defragment. Right? so automatic maintenance in Windows includes also tasks like this?

Comment: SSD and flash disks are not defragmented normally by windows systems, only if it does not or has not recognised that it is a SSD. There are many other things that go on, tracing , logging, updating $logfile and $bitmap $jrnl items, any AV scanning, if last access it turned on updating that metadata, and others. Most of that effects the disk that the system itself is on, and not as many things going on for a simple data disk.

Answer (score 2):

Removing a flash drive or ssd won't damage the drive, but you could lose data if there are any writes that haven't been committed to disk yet.